# Relationship between the autocorrelations of X(t) and X(nt)

Tags: sampling, autocorrelation, stochastic

Defining:

$X(t)$ WSS random process with autocorrelation function $R_{X}(\tau) = \mathbb{E}[X(t)X(t+\tau)]$.

$Y[n] = X(nT)$ (sampling of $X$ at a rate $\frac1T$) with autocorrelation function $R_Y(\tau) = \mathbb{E}[Y[n]Y[n+\tau]]$.

Which is the relationship between $R_X(\tau)$ and $R_Y(\tau)$?

Comment: when correlating two different signals, and $X(t)$ and $X(nt)$ are two different signals, we call that **cross-correlation** not *auto*-correlation.

Comment: What I'm interested about is in the relationship between the autocorrelation of both signals, not in the correlation between both... perhaps I expressed myself wrongly

Comment: well, it seems that one is a continuous-lag autocorrelation and the other is a discrete-lag autocorrelation, right?  only the latter can be computed for all discrete-time lags.  the continuous-time autocorrelation is a mathematical or theoretical thing.  but computers can compute the discrete-time autocorrelation.

Comment: In terms of the question: I'm intersted in the functional relationship between x(t) and Ry(t)

Comment: the difference is the difference between an exact integral and a Riemann-sum approximation to the integral.

Comment: we need to get this expressed more clearly.  i think i know what you mean to ask, but i have to change the expression of your question to make it clear.  mind if i edit your question?

Comment: I edited the question, hope now it's more clear... In case it isn't, feel free to change it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the OP's question is more straightforward than rb-j's comments make it out to be.

$\{X(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ is a *continuous-time* WSS random process with autocorrelation function 
$$R_X(\tau) = E[X[t)X(t+\tau)], -\infty < \tau < \infty.$$
On the other hand, 
$\{Y(n)\colon n \in \mathbb Z\}$ where $Y[n] = X(nT)$ is a *discrete-time* process whose mean function 
\begin{align}
\mu_Y[n] &= E\left[Y[n]\right]\\
&= E[X(nT)]\\
&= \mu_X(nT)\tag{1}\\
&= \mu_X
\end{align} 
is a constant since $\{X(t)\}$ is assumed to be WSS and so *its* mean function $\mu_X(t)$ has fixed value $\mu_X$.  Similarly, the autocorrelation function of $\{Y[n]\}$ is 
\begin{align}
R_{Y,Y}[m,n] &= E\left[Y[m]Y[n]\right]\\
&= E[X(mT)X(nT)]\\
&= R_{X,X}(mT, nT),\tag{2}\\
&= R_X((n-m)T)\end{align}
that is, the value of $R_{Y,Y}[m,n]$ depends only on the *difference* $n-m$ of the arguments $m$ and $n$, and not upon their individual values. We conclude that

> $\{Y(n)\colon n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is a discrete-time **WSS** random process with mean $\mu_X$ and autocorrelation function 
>   $$R_Y[m] = E\left[Y[n]Y[n+m]\right] = R_X(mT).$$

Note that just as the random variables $Y[n]$ are regularly spaced *samples* ($T$ seconds apart) of the $\{X(t)\}$ process, the *autocorrelation* function $R_Y[m]$ is just regularly spaced samples ($T$ seconds apart) of the autocorrelation function $R_X(\tau)$ of the $\{X(t)\}$ process. Indeed, Eqs. $(1)$ and $(2)$ show that if $\{X(t)\}$ were *not* WSS, then the mean function $\mu_Y[n]$ would be equal to $E[X(nT)] = \mu_X(nT)$, that is,  the mean function of $\{Y[n]\}$ is just regularly spaced samples of the mean function $\mu_X(t)$ of the $\{X(t)\}$ process while $$R_{Y,Y}[m,n] = E\left[Y[m]Y[n]\right] = E[X(mT)X(nT)] = R_{X,X}\left(mT, nT\right),$$
that is, the autocorrelation function $R_{Y,Y}[m,n]$ is just regularly spaced sample values of $R_{X,X}(t_1, t_2) = E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$ where the samples are on a square grid.

---

Since the OP's original question and my answer have resulted in a flood of comments and queries from rb-j that are far too many to be answered in comments, I will add something here to further explain my view of the issues, and then ignore any follow-up queries or comments. If you don't like my answer, down-vote it or write your own answer explaining your view of the matter. Both actions  will be ignored by me.

The OP's question concerns *sampling* a wide-sense-stationary (WSS) *continuous-time* process $\{X(t)\colon t \in \mathbb R\}$ to create a *discrete-time* process $\{Y[n]\colon n \in \mathbb Z\}$ where $Y[n]$ is defined to be $X(nT)$ where $T$ is a known positive constant.  The OP then asks for the relationship between the autocorrelation functions $R_X(t)$ (continuous-time)  and $R_Y[n]$ (discrete-time) of the two processes.

My answer, which I have explained in some detail, to this question,  is that $R_Y[n]$ is just the sampled version of $R_X(t)$:  $$R_Y[n] = R_X(nT)~\text{for all} ~n \in \mathbb Z.$$
This relationship **is not a two-way street;** given the values of $R_Y[n]$, it is *not possible* to reconstruct $R_X(t)$. Nor have I claimed anywhere that $R_Y[n]$ and $R_X(t)$ are the same function.  "But, but, but,$\ldots$ what about the sampling theorem? What about ergodicity? What about $\ldots$," you splutter. Please *re-read* the sampling theorem, especially the hypotheses. **If** $R_X(t)$ is a *strictly band limited* function (and nowhere has it been asserted that $R_X(t)$ enjoys this property), *then* it can be reconstructed from its sample  values *provided* the sampling rate is adequately high (exactly how high is not relevant). Given *only* sample values, one can construct *infinitely many* possible functions that have the specified sample values. *If* the  sample values *are* of a function *is* indeed strictly band limited, then one of these reconstructions will coincide with the function that was sampled. But simply to use the Shannon-Whittaker interpolation formula on $R_Y[n]$ and *insist* that the result *must be* $R_X(t)$ is something that boggles my mind, though ymmv. As for ergodicity, the less said the better.

Comment: now if the thing is WSS, it's also ergodic, no?  aren't all time averages the same as probabilistic averages?

$$\begin{align}
R_X(\tau) &= E[X(t)X(t+\tau)], -\infty < \tau < \infty.\\
&= \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} X(t)X(t+\tau) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{pdf}\{X(t)=\alpha,X(t+τ)=\beta\}(\alpha,\beta)\, \alpha \beta \, \mathrm{d}\alpha \mathrm{d}\beta \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: now for discrete time,

$$\begin{align}
R_X(\tau) &= E[X[n]X[n+\tau]], -\infty < \tau < \infty.\\
&= \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{1}{2L+1} \sum\limits_{-L}^{L} X[n]X[n+\tau] \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{pdf}\{X[n]=\alpha,X[n+τ]=\beta\}(\alpha,\beta)\, \alpha \beta \, \mathrm{d}\alpha \mathrm{d}\beta \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: it's like one is a Riemann sum  of the other.  but the $\Delta t$ is fixed at 1.  so then the lower bandwidth the WSS signal $x(t)$ is, the better the Riemann sum will approximate the integral.  That's like saying the more oversampled $X(t)$ is, the closer the Riemann sum is to the integral.

Comment: i think i forgot to restrict $\tau\in\mathbb{Z}$ in the discrete-time case.  and it's too late to edit the comment.

Comment: i think that if 

$$ X(t) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} X[n] \operatorname{sinc}(t-n) $$

then the summation and integral will be equal.

Comment: this looks right, but I'm confused about no restrictions on the sampling rate: the sampling theorem doesn't intervene here?

Comment: @MPA95 There are no restrictions on the sampling rate and the sampling theorem is irrelevant here (as is ergodicity) regardless of whatever rb_j writes. We are _not_ interested in reconstructing the $\{X(t)\}$ process from the $\{Y[n]\}$ process; $\{Y[n]\}$ is a process consisting of equally-spaced samples from the $\{X(t)\}$ process, and its mean (function) and autocorrelation function are equally-spaced samples from the mean function and autocorrelation function of the $\{X(t)\}$  process, even if the $\{X(t)\}$ process is not a WSS process.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, the OP wants to compare some property of a continuous-time signal to the corresponding property of a discrete-time signal that is the sampled version of the continuous-time signal.  and you're saying that the sampling theorem is irrelevant?

Comment: MPA, i was *"assuming"* or restricting that the sampling period is 1.  normally we can do that without loss of generality because it amounts to a change of definition of the unit of time.

Comment: i mean, @DilipSarwate, do you say that white noise as a continuous-time function is functionally the same thing as what you'ld get out of a good gaussian random number generator?  one has infinite power, the other does not.  one has a dirac delta for its autocorrelation, the other has a kronecker delta.

Comment: It is well-understood on dsp.SE (if not on math.SE) that white noise cannot be "sampled" as in "pick the $nT$-th random variable out of the collection $\{X(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$" because any sampling device has finite bandwidth and so what is being sampled is a finite-variance process.  That's why discrete-time white Gaussian noise is a sequence of i.i.d. zero-mean Gaussian random variables with autocorrelation a Kronecker delta while continuous-time Gaussian white noise is a mythical beast with autocorrelation a Dirac delta. No issues there at all.

Comment: okay, @DilipSarwate, let's say it's Johnson noise or some other very broad-banded yet finite-power noise.  can that be sampled?  what are the two autocorrelation functions?  are they the same?